# Как отлаживать программу на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите пожалуйста , как правильно отладить приложение на ассемблере . Раньше для консольных приложений использовал оли дебагер ,все было нормально , сейчас возникла потребность ГУИ приложение отладить , нужно на определенном месте кода остановится ,после нажатия на кнопку . Но при нажатии на кнопку , дебагер не останавливает, просто происходит действие по нажатию на кнопку. Подскажите пожалуйста как остановится на определенном месте и как вообще правильно нужно отлаживать программы такие.
Спасибо

Comment: Уточните платформу хотя бы. Если майкрософт, то никаких проблем с родными отладчиками не замечал, вплоть до всплытия по точкам останова внутри VxD.

Comment: Компилирую ФАСМОМ , под Винду

Comment: Емнип, ещё совсем недавно фасм просто не умел общепринятую отладочную информацию генерить. Как сейчас - не знаю.

Answer (score 3):

> нужно на определенном месте кода остановится ,после нажатия на кнопку

Можно прямо в коде в нужном месте (в начале кода, обрабатывающего нажатие на кнопку) вставлять int3. При запуске программы под отладчиком произойдет остановка исполнения в этом месте. При запуске без отладчика просто произойдет необработанное исключение, и программа будет закрыта.

> ещё совсем недавно фасм просто не умел общепринятую отладочную информацию генерить.

Начиная с версии 1.67.29 fasm умеет генерировать отладочную/символьную информацию (включается ключом `-s` при компиляции из исходника из командной строки). Используется свой собственный формат, не совместимый ни с каким другим инструментом, но есть например плагин для OllyDbg 1.10, включающий его поддержку, и есть утилиты, конвертирующие этот формат в общепринятые форматы.

Цитата с forum.flatassembler.net (тема "[Symbolic/debug information](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=9792)", пост №2):

> Tomasz Grysztar
>
> Here comes the list of the existing tools converting "fas" into some other formats (moderators, please feel free to edit this list anytime, when some new tools arrive):
>
> - Tool that generates debug info in CodeView format in COFF object files generated by fasm:
>     http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=89369
> - Linux program that dumps in text form the contents of "fas" file generated for the ELF binary:
>     http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=10029
> - Plugin for OllyDbg that loads debug info from .fas file:
>     http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=114370
> - IDA script which adds FASM debug info:
>     http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=118458
> - fasolly: yet another plugin which imports .fas into OllyDbg
>     http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=12365

Comment: Хм, ну а разве это не единственно верный и удобный способ одновременно для отладки ASM-приложений? С помощью программного бряка:

     Можно прямо в коде в нужном месте вставлять int3

Comment: @0xFFh, кроме "бряков" есть же имена меток/процедур/переменных, которые хотелось бы видеть в удобочитаемом виде.

Comment: @0xFFh, вообще-то нормальный отладчик предполагает намного большее. Даже во времена глубокого DOS можно было отлаживать драйверы (не говоря уж о простых программах), развалившись в уютном кресле какого-нибудь TD - с просмотром памяти, кода, регистров, изменением чего угодно и даже шагая по инструкциям назад, и всё это по исходникам - со всеми метками, символьными именами, переменными и т. д. Ну а для резидентов был шикарный  Quaid Analyzer... Эх :-)